# Inverses in subspace?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Why do we not have to prove that additive inverses exist in order for a subset of a vector space to be a subspace whereas in the case of groups we do? Does the existence of inverses come about from closure under scalar multiplication?

Comment: Who said you don't have to prove that? Of course you have to! Certainly, $\;(-1)\cdot v=-v\;$ , but it's just the same.

Comment: My text and the material I've seen online only specify it necessary to check the set is closed under addition, contains the additive identity and is closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: Exactly, and as written above in my first comment this is enough because existence of inverse follows from multiplying by minus the multiplicative unit. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the most logical definition, a subspace of a vector space $V$ is a subset $U$ of that is a vector space under the same addition and scalar multiplication (restricted, of course). So *in principle* you have to prove *all* the axioms of a vector space. But by the very fact that $V$ is already known to be a space, a lot can be left out, for example, associativity of addition need not be checkd in $U$ because iot holds in $V$. Similarly, we need not check that $-u \in U$ for all $u\in U$, provided we already know that $cu\in U$ for all $u\in U$, $c\in F$. This is so because we are allowed to let $c=-1$ and already know (in $V$) that $(-1)\cdot u=-u$. So what we have is a simplified test whether $U$ is a subset of $V$, or a **subspace criterion**: We need only check that $U$ is not empty, that it is closed unde addition, and closed under scalar multiplication. Essentially, we have just shown most of the claim that any subset with these properties is a subspace.

There is a similar situation with groups: A subgroup is a subset of a group that happens to be a group under the given (restricted) group operation. Again, we do not have to check *all* properties, e.g., associativity is - again - for free. The lack of scaler multiplication seems to require that we always have to show the closure under taking inverses, but in fact this is not *always* the case. There is a **subgroup criterion** for the special case of **finite** groups which only requires one to check that the presumed subgroup is non-empty and closed under the group operation!

Comment: This last criterion works, more generally, for torsion groups.